# TLDS- Do .INFO domain names perform differently than other domain names?

Tags: seo, domain-name

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using .info domain names? They are certainly cheaper, but I'd like to know whether search engines or human users have known issues with them.  For example, do search engines rank .com or .org lower than .info?

I am about to purchase forty or fifty domain names and I want some good info.

Any ideas or experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLD has no effect on SEO except for local search. Since .info is a general TLD and not a country specific TLD using it will not have an impact on your rankings at all.

Comment: What about from a user perspective? Do you think users see the .info and think any more or less about the potential content?

Comment: People tend to recognize more common TLDs like .com or .net versus lesser known ones like .info. But nowadays since most sites are found through links of some kind and .info has been around for a long time I doubt there would be any perceived positive or negative effect from using a .info TLD.